# Flutter pub get does not install in Dart Packages

Tags: flutter

I tried to import english_words package from flutter package website for developer in Android Studio.
Flutter pub get does not working.
In terminal, tried to push 'flutter pub get' command,
in pubspec.yaml, pushed 'Pub get' button,
at the topbar, pushed 'Pub get' button.
And also I tried another packages, but it didn't come any packages in my Dart Packages.

Please anyone help me.....

Comment: your image shows that the command ended without errors in 0.4 secs, how did you know it is failing